# Custom runtime dockerfile for asp.net core 5 with Google cloud error CS1003: Syntax error,

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to publish the Asp.net core 5 application to the google cloud using the visual studio plugin.

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

**Docker file**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Falcon-Identity.dll"]
```

When I publish using publish to google cloud from context menu I am getting the below exception

```
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(1,23): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(1,23): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(1,30): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(1,30): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(1,31): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(1,37): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(1,37): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(1,41): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(2,9): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(2,9): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(2,10): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(3,3): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(4,6): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(4,8): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(4,16): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(4,16): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(4,17): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(5,12): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(6,3): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(7,6): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(7,10): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(8,12): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(8,20): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(8,20): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(8,21): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(8,31): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(8,32): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(8,34): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(8,34): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(9,3): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Falcon-Identity.csproj]
C:\Projects\falcon-identity\Falcon-Identity\Dockerfile(10,9): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' e
```

Comment: Can you run the container image locally without issue i.e. `(PORT=8080 && docker run --interactive --tty --rm --env=PORT=${PORT} --publish=${PORT}:${PORT} your-image`?

Comment: Flex (like Cloud Run) is essentially a container runner so, if the container runs (somewhere else), it should work on e.g. App Engine. "essentially" because port `8080` is critical to both services and Google sandboxes its runtimes for security so there's a probability of less than 100% fidelity.

Comment: I am repro'ing a basic ASP.NET example and I think an issue you have is setting `ENV ASPNETCORE_URL`. In my simpler example I can access the server on `:8080` if I use `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--urls=http://+:8080"]`

Comment: Does the project build locally, outside of Docker? Does the container build locally? It looks to me like something is trying to build your `dockerfile` as application code.

Comment: @DanielMann yes the project build, without the docker

Comment: I think that the source of the issue is not docker, I think is the way you are deploying the container, since you are using a visual studio plugin some file might be corrupted, could you check the file that error is saying that the error is and confirm that everything is ok. Also I would suggest you to deploy it through a terminal like the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered an identical problem with same exceptions.
It was caused by setting the build action on the docker file incorrectly (properties tab - incorrectly set the build action of the file to "C# compiler" instead of "None").

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine: As I created the Dockerfile using VisualStudio, it has changed the .csproj inserting the following lines:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Dockerfile" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

commeting it out solved the problem.

It was clear the reason of the error, right? the dotnet was trying to compile it, thus the syntax error thrown.